# How can I run the Ubuntu EC2 AMI images locally?

Tags: amazon-ec2, virtualbox, amazon-ami

I've downloaded the Amazon Ubuntu EC2 AMI images (from http://uec-images.ubuntu.com/releases/10.04/release/) and I am trying to run it locally on my linux desktop. Is it possible to run the AMI using VirtualBox? Is some other virtualization software required?

Answer (score 6):

Link provided Istvan is down.

Amazon now provides tool to export your EC2 image as Virtual Machine image ready to run locally:

http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/vmimport/

**PS Please note that this method only works for Windows VMs**

> Export the instance using the ec2-create-instance-export-task command.
>   The export command captures the parameters necessary (instance ID, S3
>   bucket to hold the exported image, name of the exported image, VMDK,
>   OVA or VHD format) to properly export the instance to your chosen
>   format. The exported file is saved in an S3 bucket that you previously
>   created

*October 2016 update: You're able to create VM images from several Unix/Linux AMIs as well*

Comment: EC2 image can be exported as VM from AWS only if it was imported to AWS. From documentation it is clear that native (non-imported VMs) cannot be exported from AWS.